# Spring form validation with extra fields

Tags: spring-mvc, validation

I'm writing an application with Spring framework and I have a question how to do a form validation with extra fields.

I'm new to this but as far as I understand to fill the form with form:form tag I set attribute with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(Model model) {

    model.addAttribute("tenant", new Tenant());                     
    return "register";
}
```

Then create validator class and use it on POST request:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registerPost(@ModelAttribute("tenant") Tenant tenant, 
                    Model model,
                    BindingResult result) {

    TenantValidator validator = new TenantValidator();
    validator.validate(tenant, result);  
    if (result.hasErrors()) { 
        return "register"; 
    } 

    tenantService.save(tenant);
    return "redirect:accountOverview";
}
```

It works very well and I'm fascinated by how convenient this is!

The only problem is what do I do with extra fields?
For example I have "repeat password" field.
If I create extra fields without using  tags and by using  and validate them directly I would not be able to use:

```
<form:errors path="repeatPassword>
```

tag as 'repeatPassword' is not a member of form object.

The first solution that comes to mind is to create special form object TenantDTO that would hold those extra fields and on save just transfer the data to 'Tenant' (entity bean).

Is this a good approach? What are the best practices in this situation?

Thanks!

Leonty

Answer (score 0):

You can still have these values in the form object. I guess you don't want to save these to the database. You can avoid that by using the annotation Transient (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/Transient.html). This will give a leverage for you to do the path mapping, having in the form object and do all the validation but still dont save in the database. hope it helps.

Comment: This is something I haven't thought of.
My concern is that my entity class would have form functionality (by having those extra fields). This is in EJB, so another application which would use this bean would receive an object with fields that are not useful at all(for that particular application). Hope what I'm saying makes sense. In short - I want to have Separation of Concerns as good as possible.